# Excel IF statement to filter numbers and letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use an IF statement in excel so that I can populate a number of cells with yes or no depending on the result. The problem I have is that the items I would like to filter start with 2 letters and either have 5 or 6 numbers after the letters depending on the item. I would like to filter it so that if the item contains 6 numbers after the 2 starting letters then the letter N is produced in the cell next to it and if the item has 5 numbers after the starting letters then a Y should be produced in the cell.  
 Here is an example of the items to which I am referring: 
JJ230315 
TT22252   
 In the cells next to these items then I would like to produce either Y or N.
 Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To clarify:  Do you have any instances where you have 3 letters and 4/5 numbers, or can this just be treated as "Length is 7 (Y) or 8 (N)characters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have data in column `A`, use:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=8,"N","Y")
```

Comment: This does zero validation as per the original problem.  It only checks length.

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen said - _JJJJJJJJ_ will return "N" as will _12345678_, a blank cell will return "Y" as will _This doesn't start with two letters and has no numbers_.  On the other hand, if you just want to return "Y" if there's exactly 8 characters in a cell and "N" otherwise then this is perfect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't validate, but the problem seems not to be with validation, rather with length - that's what I figured from question and examples.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I use a formula for the `"Y"` condition.  Everything else would then be labeled as `"N"`.  One approach is to use the `CODE()` function to assert that each of the first two characters are either uppercase or lowercase letters.  Then, we can use `ISNUMBER()` on the remaining five characters to assert that they are numeric.

```
=IF(AND(OR(AND(CODE(MID(A1,1,1))>=65,CODE(MID(A1,1,1))<=90),
    AND(CODE(MID(A1,1,1))>=97,CODE(MID(A1,1,1))<=122)),
        OR(AND(CODE(MID(A1,2,1))>=65,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))<=90),
    AND(CODE(MID(A1,2,1))>=97,CODE(MID(A1,2,1))<=122)),
        ISNUMBER(MID(A1, 3, 5)*1),
        LEN(A1) = 7), "Y", "N")
```